# If $f''(x) \gt 0$ for $x\in(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then $0 \gt f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Tags: calculus

I find a word in my calculus exercise book. It says that:

> If $f''(x) \gt 0$ for $x\in(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then $0 \gt f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

I try to prove this. First, since $f''(x) \gt 0$, so $f'(x)$ is increasing in interval $(a,b)$. However, I don't know how to continue the proof. I want to use IVT, but the three kinds of IVT need that $f(x)$ also continious in $[a,b]$, in this statement, I can not prove $f(x)$ is continious at point $a$ or $b$.

In my opinion, if we want to prove that $0 \gt f(x)$, I try to prove that $0 \gt\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}  \forall x \in (a,b)$ and use Lagerange theorem, but I can't prove that continuity at $a$ otr $b$.

In fact, I think that maybe this statement is false. Can anyone tell me if this statement right and if it is right how to prove it?

ps: I construct this counterexample. (I can't be sure about the correctness.)

[image]

Comment: @Koro In my graph, $f(a)=f(b)=0$, my construction means that $f(x)$ is discontinious at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ah! I see. Discontinuity at $a$ and $b$. I take my previous comment back.

Comment: I think the question should mention that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ otherwise as your graph shows the result is false.

Comment: For continuous $f$ you can see that derivative vanishes somewhere in $(a, b) $ by Rolle and since it is strictly increasing, it is negative before that point and positive after that point. You can now see that $f$ is negative in $(a, b) $.

Comment: The statement from the textbook is only true for functions continous on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 4):

The condition $f(a)=f(b)=0$ means nothing without continuity at $a$ and $b$.  A counter-example would be $f(x)=e^{x}$ for $a <x<b$ and $0$ for $x=a$ and $x=b$.

Assuming continuity at $a$ and $b$ we can prove this as follows.

$f$ is a convex function so $f(x)=f(ta+(1-t)b) \leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)=0$ where $t=\frac {b-x} {b-a}$. So $f(x) \leq 0$. It remains to prove strict inequality. If $f(x)=0$ for some $x \in (a,b)$ then MVT shows that $f'(s)=0$ and $f'(t)=0$ for some points $s \in (a,x)$ and $t \in (x,b)$.  But then $f''(z)=0$ for some $z$ between $s$ and $t$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: Usually the definition of convex functions is not via the sign of the second derivative but via the inequality $f(ta+(t-t)b)\leq\ldots$. So your statement "$f$ is a convex function and this implies..." is slightly misleading, since from a definition point of view its the other way round. (It is no error though since they are equivalent anyways)

Comment: I am not saying that $f''(x) >0$ is the definition of convexity. [In fact it is not even equivalent since strict inequality is not neede for convexity]. I am using a  theorem which says that $f''(x) >0$ implies convexity. @maxmilgram

Comment: You are saying: "$f$ is a convex funtion and that implies it satisfies the definition of convex functions." Its true but not meaningful. A better option would be: "$f''(x)>0$ implies that $f$ is convex, which by definition means ..."

Comment: When I say 'this implies' I am pointiting out that any point $x$ of $(a,b)$ is a  convex combination of $a$ and $b$, so the definition of convexity can be used. Anyway, I have editded the answer. @maxmilgram

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(u)\geq 0$, $u\in (a,b)$.

First case: $f(u)=0$. There exists $v_1\in (a,u), v_2\in (u,b)$ with $f'(v_1)=f'(v_2)=0$ implies there exists $w\in (v_1,v_2)$ such that $f"(w)=0$.

Case 2. $f(u)>0$, there exist $v_1\in (a,u), v_2\in (u,b)$ with $f(v_1)=f(v_2)>0$ implies there exists $w\in (v_1,v_2)$ with $f'(w)=0$. Since $f">0$, it implies that for every $x<w$, $f'(x)\leq f'(w)=0$, implies that $f$ decreases on $[a,w]$, we deduce that $f(a)\geq f(v_1)$ since $v_1<w$, contradiction.

Comment: Sorry to pester you again but the answer still is not correct. You can not show that you have two distinct (!) $c_1,c_2$.